# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un Select Dinamico en jQuery?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, ajax, select

Por favor, necesito ayuda con un código que estoy realizando en PHP + MYSQL + jQuery. Lo que necesito es saber cómo capturar el valor de un Select Dinámico que fue llenado con registros de mi tabla.

```
//Estoy usando el .val() pero aun no asi no logro capturar el valor del select.
var responsable_asignado=$('#responsable_asignado').val();
```

```html
<!--Este es el SQL que utilizo para traer los registros de mi tabla-->
<?php 
$sqlUSERS = "SELECT * FROM tb_usuarios";
$resultUSERS = $mysqli->query($sqlUSERS);
?>                                              
<select name="responsable_asignado" 
    style="width:100%" class="form-control" id="responsable_asignado">
<?php 
while($rowUSERS=$resultUSERS->fetch_assoc()){
?>
<!--Aqui relleno los registros obtenidos-->
<option value="<?php echo $rowUSERS['user_t'];?>" 
   <?php 
     if (!(strcmp($rowEditPENDU['user_apenom'], 
       htmlentities($rowUSERS['user_apenom'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8')))) {
       echo "SELECTED";
     } ?>>
      <?php echo $rowUSERS['user_apenom'];?></option><?php  
}?>                                                 
</select>
```

Nota: el `If` dentro del `option` solo me sirve para comparar valores obtenidos con otra tabla y, si son iguales, se queda el valor seleccionado. Y eso sí funciona.

El valor quiero capturar al hacer un click en un boton que seria algo como eso (PERO NO CAPTURA NADA, SALE UN VALOR EN BLANCO):

```js
$(document).on('click','#btnEditar', function(e)
{
var responsable_asignado=$('#responsable_asignado').val();
alert (responsable_asignado);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que te falta detectar el cambio con el evento onChange y seleccionar el elemento después de la carga del html.

Puedes intentar con el siguiente código:

```
var responsable_asignado = "";
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#responsable_asignado').change(function(){
        responsable_asignado = $(this).val();
        alert(responsable_asignado);
    });
});
```

> EDITADO

Para hacerlo con el evento click a otro boton se escribe muy similar, aqui te dejo el codigo.

```html
<select name="responsable_asignado" id="responsable_asignado">
  <option value="opcion1">opcion 1</option>
  <option value="opcion2">opcion 2</option>
  <option value="opcion3">opcion 3</option>    
</select>
<button id="btnEditar">Editar</button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btnEditar").on("click", function () {
    var responsable_asignado=$('#responsable_asignado').val();
    alert (responsable_asignado);
  })
})
```

Tambien te dejo este ejemplo en codepen:
https://codepen.io/rtelenta/pen/BEVQBy

Comment: Hola Renzo me olvide aclarar que estoy necesitando capturar dentro de una funcion: $(document).on('click','#btnEditar', function(e){ } en ese caso como seria?

Comment: Hola, el código seria el mismo solo necesitas cambiar el change por click. Voy a editar la respuesta para dejarte un link de codepen.

Comment: Gracias Renzo pero no esta capturando el valor, me sale en blanco, tiene que ver algo si mi codigo esta junto a una datatable serverside?

Comment: Hola, lo mas probable en este caso puede ser que el html no esta pintando como debería. Podrías tomar una captura del select y y los options con el inspector de elementos del navegador?